# .htaccess redirect .jpg files which contains (.pl) in its filename

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

This is my url mysite.com/screenshot/a/b/c/imgname.pl.jpg

Whenever I go to this url it redirects to not found.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
Options -Multiviews
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^screenshot/(.*)$ /screenshot/tempthumb.jpg [NC,L]

#it looks like htaccess is taking my url as a .pl perl file. 
#So This is what I have tried.

RewriteRule ^screenshot/(.*)(.)(pl.jpg)$ /screenshot/$1\.$3 [NC,L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ ./page.php?permalink=$1 [L]
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <filesMatch "\.(js|css|html|php)$">
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    </filesMatch>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript
</IfModule>
```

Ehat could be the problem

Answer (score 0):

My guess as to what the problem could be is it's trying to look for a file called, literally, `pl.jpg`. Try making it into `*.pl.jpg`?

Comment: could you explain more.

Comment: You put on your code that you had a filter looking for `pl.jpg`, so it's trying to filter all files out but `pl.jpg`.